# Azure DevOps run Pipeline when GitHub is pushed but ignore some certain files

Tags: github, azure-devops

I have a Pipeline on Azure DevOps that runs automatically - the trigger is a push to the `master` branch of my GitHub repo.

This pipeline will build a Docker image and push it to container registry, restart the app, etc. to update the app with the latest changes.

However, there are some certain files I want this Pipeline to ignore (for example, `README.md`). Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can a path filter for your pipeline trigger.

If you are using yaml pipeline. You can set the path filter as below:

```
trigger:
  batch: true  
  branches:
    include:
    - master
   paths:
    exclude:
    - README.md
```

If you are using classic UI pipeline. You can go to the `Triggers` tab and set the path filter

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at that but didn’t know exactly how to do it. I know now!